# "Stay long" vs. "stay for long."

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Example sentence:

> I won't stay **long/for long**, I promise.

Is one option more idiomatic than the other? Or both are idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I won't stay long*** is definitely the idiomatic way of expressing it. *I won't stay for long* does exist but is [much more rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20stay%20long%2Cnot%20stay%20for%20long&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20stay%20long%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20stay%20for%20long%3B%2Cc0).

Note that

> We use ***long*** as an *adverb* ***in questions and negative clauses*** to talk about duration. *We don’t use **long*** on its own ***in affirmative clauses.*** We often use (for) a long time:
>
> - We waited ***for a long time*** in the rain for the bus.
>   Not: … <del>waited long</del> … ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/long))

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One question. In the phrase: "No matter how long she waited ..." It's not technically a question, but the (for) is omitted because of the "how"?

Comment: It is an embedded question, but an [indirect](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/indirect_questions.htm#:~:text=An%20indirect%20question%20is%20a,i.e.%2C%20an%20interrogative%20sentence) one. So yes, you can use here "ong" on its own because of how. As in "I don't know how long she waited."